# Excel Export as PDF - Select specific worksheets based on a name range with Yes or No switch

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-generation

is it possible to specify specific worksheets to print within a workbook using a small named range with Y or N acting as a switch?

In the workbook there is an "Inputs" worksheet that allows a person to select various options that will produce a custom report. A section of the "Inputs" is meant to allow a person to select which worksheets to include in the PDF by choosing either Y or N. The workbook has a number of worksheets in it that the user may want to export into the PDF file that correspond to the Report Pages listed in a small table on the "Inputs" worksheet with a Named Range of "Y_N_Print" that contains the following data:

| Report Pages | Include |
| --- | --- |
| Inputs | N |
| Cover | Y |
| Trend | Y |
| NIE | Y |
| Spreads | Y |

The idea is to include the "Cover" worksheet in the single PDF file if there is a Y next to it and so forth.

Here is the current code that exports the worksheets into a PDF workbook and it does function but it has to be maintained manually in the code rather than by selecting Y or N in the "Y_N_Print" Named Range:

Sub ExportAsPDF()
Dim filePath As Variant
Dim defaultFileName As String

```
defaultFileName = Range("File_Name").Value
filePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=defaultFileName, _
    FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", Title:="Save PDF As...")
If filePath = False Then Exit Sub
  
Sheets(Array("Cover", "Trend", "NIE")).Select 'Update the list of worksheet names here
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=filePath, _
    openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False

Sheets("Inputs").Activate
MsgBox "The PDF report has been successfully exported."
```

End Sub

Is there a way to automatically update the values in this part of the code to match the values that have a Y next to them?
Sheets(Array("Cover", "Trend", "NIE")).Select

The code below works to a degree. It includes the worksheets with a Y next to them, but there doesn't seem to be a way to stop it from including the "Inputs" worksheet. It is highly unlikely that one would want to include the "Inputs" worksheet.

Sub ExportAsPDF()
Dim filePath As Variant
Dim defaultFileName As String
Dim sheetsToExport As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

```
Set sheetsToExport = Range("Y_N_Print") '"Y_N_Print" is the named range

defaultFileName = Range("File_Name").Value
filePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=defaultFileName, _
    FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", Title:="Save PDF As...")
If filePath = "False" Then Exit Sub

For Each cell In sheetsToExport
    If UCase(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "Y" Then ' Checks if the value in the second column is "Y"
        On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors if worksheet name is not found
        Set ws = Worksheets(cell.Value) ' Get worksheet with name in the first column
        On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then ' If worksheet exists, select it
            ws.Select False
        End If
    End If
Next cell

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=filePath, _
    openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False

Sheets("Inputs").Activate
MsgBox "The PDF report has been successfully exported."
```

End Sub

Comment: Maybe `If UCase(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "Y" Then sh = sh & "," & cell.Value: Next`. ... `Sheets(Split(Mid(sh, 2), ",")).Select` ... `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=filePath, _
    openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False` ... `Sheets("Inputs").Activate` It create sh variable as sheet name collection. Then it select the sheets in sh all together, then export as pdf.